# Using promise, resolve and axios and get multiple same returns each time GET

Tags: node.js, reactjs, http, axios, promise

I am currently learning nodejs and react, and I want to achieve data transmission between frontend and backend. During this, I found that every time I refresh the website, the console in the browser would print out the content several times.
Here is my frontend code  for post, get data and display data result.

callAPI.js

```js
import axios from 'axios'
const api = 'http://localhost:5000'

class callAPI{
    getSomething(){
        return new Promise((resolve)=>resolve(axios.get(`${api}`)))
    }
    sendSomething(body){
        return new Promise((resolve)=>resolve(axios.post(`${api}/hello`,body)))
    }
}
export default new callAPI()`
```

Page.js

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import callAPI from './callAPI';

export default function Page(){
    const[content, setContent] = useState("")
    const[greeting, setGreeting] = useState("")

    function getContent(){
        callAPI.getSomething().then(response=>{
            console.log(response.data)
            setContent(response.data)
        })
    }
    function handleLB(){
        callAPI.sendSomething({name:"Sam"})
        .then((response)=>{
            console.log(response.data)
            setGreeting(response.data)
        })
    }
    function handleCC(){
        callAPI.sendSomething({name:"Mary"})
        .then((response)=>{
            console.log(response.data)
            setGreeting(response.data)
        })
    }
    getContent()
    console.log(content)
    return(
        <>
            <h1>{content}</h1>
            <div>
                <button onClick={handleLB}>Sam is comming</button>
                <button onClick={handleCC}>Mary is comming</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>{greeting}</p>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Here is my backend code
app.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express();

const greeting={"Sam":"Handsome boy","Mary":"Young and beautiful lady"}

var corsOptions={
    credentiala:true,
    origin:'http://localhost:3000',
    optionsSuccessStatus:200
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions))

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/',function(req, res) {
    res.send('Knock knock, who\'s coming?')
})

app.post('/hello',function(req, res){
    //console.log(req.body.name)
    let grt = greeting[req.body.name]
    res.send(grt)
})
app.listen(5000,function(){
    console.log('App is listening on port 5000...')
})
```

And here is a picture of my browser console[image: When i get into the website, it returns a bunch of same strings.]

In my understanding, each GET/POST should only have one return results. In this case, when I POST something, I only get one return results. But for GET, I get multiple. And I'm really curious why this would happen.

Comment: You've implemented the [explicit promise construction anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/283366). Axios already returns a promise, you don't need to create new ones

Comment: You need to move your `getContent()` call into an effect hook, otherwise it will execute on every render... `useEffect(() => { getContent(); }, []);`

Comment: @Phil So the reason that I get several same return is that every time I refresh the page, the code execute several times? And using useEffect make sure that the function getContent() only execute on time. Do I understand it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all axios return promise by itself so don't need to put again in Promises and call getContent using useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
 getContent() 
},[])
```

In dependency array you can have some dependency or leave it blank(so it will call the getContent only once time)